# Numpy: Conserving sum in average over two arrays of integers

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have two arrays of positive integers A and B that each sum to 10:

- A = [1,4,5]
- B = [5,5,0]

I want to write a code (*that will work for a general size of the array and the sum*) to calculate the array C who is **also a array of positive integers** that **also sums to 10** that is the **closest to the element-wise average as possible**:

- Pure average `C = (A + B) / 2`: C=[3,4.5,2.5]
- Round `C = np.ceil((A + B) / 2).astype(int)`: C=[3,5,3], (sum=11, incorrect!)
- Fix the sum `C = SOME CODE`: c=[3,4,3], (sum=10, correct!)

Any value can be adjusted to make the sum correct, as long as all elements remain positive integers.

What should `C = SOME CODE` be?

Minimum reproducible example:

```
A = np.array([1,4,5])
B = np.array([5,5,0])
C = np.ceil((A + B) / 2).astype(int)
print(np.sum(C))

11
```

This should give 10.

Comment: Unfortunately this is not a code-writing or tutorial service. Please include a [mcve] including _code_ for what you've tried based on your own research, and what was wrong with your attempt

Comment: @G.Anderson ```C = np.ceil((A + B) / 2).astype(int)``` what what I tried, what was wrong as stated is the sum is incorrect.

Comment: In that case though you need to decide whether each element needs to be rounded up or down based off the running average. Is it ALWAYS going to be a sum of 10?

Comment: @Chrispresso Thanks! The sum is a constant, for this example 10 but could in principle be any value.

Comment: Also, are you saying you want to change a value? Like you want to change the 5 in A to 6?

Comment: @Chrispresso change the values in C such the sum is the same as the sum of A and B, in this case 10

Comment: Have you considered rounding instead of taking the ceiling?

Comment: @MadPhysicist rounding down results in the sum being too small, and up too large.

Comment: @jw1294. There is no one-shot solution. Have you tried actually rounding, not floor or ceil?

Comment: @MadPhysicist Rounding rounds to closest, in this case up.

Comment: @jw1294. Numpy uses banker's rounding, so not true

Comment: @MadPhysicist np.round also results in the same incorrect result as in the question. Bankers rounding would only work in the limit of infinite elements.

Comment: @jw1294. Agreed, but for a different reason

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can ceil/floor every other non-int element. This works for any shape/size and any sum value (in fact you do not need to know the sum at all. It is enough if `A` and `B` have same sum):

```
C = (A + B) / 2
C_c = np.ceil(C)
C_c[np.flatnonzero([C!=C.astype(int)])[::2]] -= 1

print(C_c.sum())
#10.0
print(C_c.astype(int))
#[3 4 3]
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok so based off what you're saying, this could work:

```py
C = ((a + b) / 2)  # array([3, 4, 2])
curr_sum = sum(C)  # 9
adjust_amount = sum(a) - curr_sum  # 10-9 = 1
if adjust_amount > 0:
    C[-1] += adjust_amount  # array([3, 4, 3])
# Otherwise if it's negative just grab the largest and subtract to ensure you still remain >0
else:
    C[np.argmax(C)] += adjust_amount
```